# How to correct added records to the table with correct order number on SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How to correct added records to the table with correct order number on SQL Server 2000?

I have the following ordered table:

```
OrderNo Data
      0    A
      1    B
      2    C
```

I need to add the following records to the table (with order saving):

```
OrderNo Data
      2    E
      3    F
      1    D
```

And to get the following as the result on the table:

```
OrderNo Data
      0    A
      1    B
      2    C
      3    D
      4    E
      5    F
```

How to do this on SQL Server 2000?

P.S. OrderNo can't be identity or unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulating `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL Server 2000

```
select (select count(*) 
        from Table1 as e2
        where e2.OrderNo <= e1.OrderNo) as OrderNo, e1.Data
from Table1 as e1
ORDER BY OrderNo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30544/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is orders...

```
SELECT count(order_count.OrderNo), orders.Data
FROM orders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN orders order_count
    ON order_count.Data < orders.Data
GROUP BY orders.Data
```

Comment: Left outer is very slow query.

Comment: For either the left outer join, or the sub select in the select clause solution (by @Kuya John) you would want an index on the Data field for performance.

Comment: Do you know this query is slow from timing it?  If you are using general knowledge, then remember correlated queries are very slow.

Comment: It should not have been, and I can see the reason.  My original read of the question was to order the table by the Data column, but reset the OrderNo to 0 to N-1.  You probably have an index on OrderNo, but no index on Data.  Changing the "ON ..." to use OrderNo instead of Data would be an fair comparison in performance.